# Given 8 cube vertices and a point inside, find two points that a line going from inside point with vector V cuts the surface of the cube.

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have the coordinates of a vertices of a cube and a point inside the cube. Now I draw a line from that point with vector **V**. How can I  find the coordinates in which that line cuts the cube surface.

Comment: Show your attempts.

Comment: I first calculate the plane which all the surfaces are in. Then find the cutting point of the line with all these planes. Now my problem is how to determine which one of the cutting points are withing the cube surfaces. There should be 2 points and in rare case that it meets at edge it should be 4.

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematican's answer, or are you writing a computer program and need an algorithm?

Comment: Is the cube axis aligned?

Comment: @MJD I am writing a computer program, but a mathematical answer is also good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the point inside the cube, and $\textbf{v}$ the vector.
For each of the six faces of the cube, find the point where the ray from $p$
in direction $\textbf{v}$ intersects the plane. The ray can be represented as $p + t \,\textbf{v}$, where $t \ge 0$ is a parameter. Solve for the $t$ that places
$p + t \,\textbf{v}$ on each plane. Discard the negative $t$ solutions.
The smallest positive $t$ solution represents the first plane hit by the ray.
This is the point you seek.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I find the distance of intersection points with p, and the one with the lowest value is my plane?

Comment: @VegaBrothers: If $\textbf{v}$ is a unit vector, then $t$ will be the distance. Yes, the closest one is the first one hit by the ray.